# StateServer sessionState and JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, stateserver

My users are constantly logged off the web app, so I am trying to use `<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="480" />` but I get a server error 500 because JQGrid cannot be serialized. Any ideas?

Comment: jqGrid just send HTTP request to the server. The error 500 means an error in the server code.Login/logout state of the user is pure server problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Oleg. I use JQGrid MVC, lots of server-side code. The error 500 occurs because all session state data must be serialized in StateServer session state mode. I am unable to serialize my instances of JQGrid in the model on the server. In other words, all the pages work fine which do not have a JQGrid instance but none that have one work and emit an error 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using

```
Session["MyGridState"] = model.MyGrid.GetState();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Webconfig sessionState to InProc and change IIS WorkerProcess to 1

```
"<system.web>    
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25"></sessionState>
```

Comment: No, I want to use StateServer because for some reason w3wp.exe keeps terminating hourly and I do not want my users logged off.